# Conditional slides in R markdown (beamer presentation)

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown, beamer

Is it possible to have conditional slides in R markdown (beamer presentation)? I tried using R code chunk hacks with `results = 'asis'` and further tried using custom LaTeX commands but to no avail. One problem seems to be that each markdown slide delimiter actually results in the combination of both

```
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
```

so it is hard to conditionally exclude a slide.